# The script is writing a new line beside the first line instead of being last line on a txt

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

My script has to iterations. On the first one, it reads a txt, takes the firt line and after doing some stuff (creating new string), it writes that string on a temp file and after deleting the original txt, it saves the temp file with the same name as the original txt.

On second iteration, it takes the created txt and tries to write a new line at the end of the file. The problem is that now the code is writing the new line beside the first line, instead of writing it in the last line.

Example:

**Expected result:** 
004;J2Yf;18090023;20200725;00000509990;VOLVO;D;YFWfS9Z9lu06JM0Rk;D;FA;18090023
**004;J2Yf;18090023;20200725;00000509990;VOLVO;D;YFWfS9Z9lu06ftR78;D;FA;18090023**

**Incorrect result:**
004;J2Yf;18090023;20200725;00000509990;VOLVO;D;YFWfS9Z9lu06JM0Rk;D;FA;18090023**004;J2Yf;18090023;20200725;00000509990;VOLVO;D;YFWfS9Z9lu06ftR78;D;FA;18090023**

How can I write on the last line?

TIA ;)

```
For Iterator 1 to 2
    sF1 = "C:\Users\ig.ext\Desktop\Automation\Archivo.txt"
    '#Opening file  
    Dim objFS 
    Dim objFile
    strTemp = "C:\Users\" & Environment("UserName") & "\Desktop\Automation\Temp.txt"
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Iterator = 1 Then

        Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(sF1)
        content = objFile.ReadLine

        '#Creating temporal file
        Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)
    Else 
        Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(sF1, 8)        

    End If

    sResultado = "004;J2Yf;18090023;20200725;00000509990;VOLVO;D;YFWfS9Z9lu06ftR78;D;FA;18090023"

    If Iterator = 1 Then

        '#Write and close
        objOutFile.Write(sResultado)

        objOutFile.Close
        objFile.Close
        objFS.DeleteFile(sF1)
        objFS.MoveFile strTemp,sF1
    else

        '#Write line and close
        objFile.Writeline(sResultado)
        objFile.Close
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Use WriteLine() instead of Write() in your first iteration to add a newline before writing the second line.

Comment: Thanks!! now works as expected ;)

Comment: @GeertBellekens please add this as an answer

Comment: @Motti no thanks. Not for something this trivial. But you may add your own answer if you would like to.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, if someone has a similar problem they may see this question has no answers and not click through to see your comment. There's no shame in posting trivial stuff if it helps people

Comment: @GeertBellekens, since you haven't added the answer I have (as community wiki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @[Geert Bellekens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018133/geert-bellekens) commented:

> Use WriteLine() instead of Write() in your first iteration to add a newline before writing the second line.

<sup>(answer added as *community wiki*)</sup>